# What is a simple way to Git Push to another machine?

Tags: git

I thought I can do the following:

```
machine1 $ cd /
           mkdir try-git
           cd try-git
           git init

machine2 $ git push ssh://loginname@192.168.1.123//try-git master
```

and that's it?  `machine1` will have all the files then? (`machine2`'s current directory is a git repo).   But on `machine2`, I keep on having `git-receive-pack: command not found`, but both machines have the latest Git 1.7.4 installed...

---

**update:** seems like I need to add

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin
```

to both machine's `.bashrc`

but why and won't invoking bash add more and more path to it.

Comment: But is `git-receive-pack` (and git in general) in the PATH of `loginname` on the other end?

Comment: if I run `git`... it knows where to find git and run it...  (it is `/usr/local/git/bin/git`)

Comment: `git-receive-pack` may not be in the same location. Try a `which git-receive-pack` on machine1.

Comment: it says it is `/usr/local/git/bin/git-receive-pack`

Comment: besides, I can `ssh loginname@192.168.1.123` and use git, git-receive-pack... as if I am on that machine

Comment: @動靜能量: With respect to your PATH issues, it's possible that your bashrc detects whether it's being used by an interactive shell, and behaves differently in each case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to push a whole repo to another machine? The easiest way would be to do a "git clone" from the destination machine to the source machine.

Comment: that's easier than doing it from the source machine?

Comment: it will say `bash: git-upload-pack: command not found` if I do `git clone` on the destination machine instead...

Comment: Does the destination machine have git properly installed? It sounds like its partially broken.

Comment: please see update for setting PATH.  also, what if I don't want to clone but want to push, say if the path on machine2 is really long, and I would like to do a push for current directory.

Comment: @動靜能量: For the initial transfer, a clone is definitely the way to go - you can't create a repository by pushing - but after that, yes, abbreviating the URL is quite possible - see my answer!

Comment: The question is how to do a "push" clone. Clone is not very useful if you are behind a firewall and have to set up port forwarding etc.

Answer (score 15):

If the remote system does not have Git in the system-default PATH (which is probably different from PATH in your login shell), then you have to tell it where to find *git-receive-pack*.

You mentioned the pathname `/usr/local/git/bin/git-receive-pack`, so try this:

```
git push --receive-pack=/usr/local/git/bin/git-receive-pack ssh://user@machine1:/try-git master
```

The pathname specified with `--receive-pack=` is the pathname of *git-receive-pack* on the remote system.

You can save the *git-receive-pack* pathname as part of a “remote” to save typing if you plan on accessing that repository many times:

```
git remote add machine1 ssh://user@machine1:/try-git
git config remote.machine1.receivepack /usr/local/git/bin/git-receive-pack
git config remote.machine1.uploadpack /usr/local/git/bin/git-upload-pack
```

Use it like this:

```
git push machine1 master
```

The `remote.<remote-name>.uploadpack` configuration variable eliminates the need for the `--upload-pack=` option to `git fetch` (and `git pull`) in the same way that `remote.<remote-name>.receivepack` eliminates the need to specify `--receive-pack=` with `git push`.

---

In your specific scenario, you are pushing to a non-bare repository. You are also probably pushing to the branch that is checked out (pushing `master` on machine2 to `master` on machine1). Modern versions of Git will give you an error when you try to do this. You can override the warning, by setting certain configuration variables, but it is usually not the best way to operate.

Comment: yes, it seems like I need to add something to `.bashrc`  please see update

Comment: if that wasn't the best way to operate, then what is the best way?  The goal is just to have two identical repo, showing all the files on both machines.  If I use `git init --bare`, then the push will not show error, but machine1's folder do not have all the files -- it is merely a repo with the git data.  `git clone` works, but what if I want to push?

Comment: 動靜能量: What do you plan on doing with the repositories after they have been established? Is this a one-time copy or do you plan on doing further synchronization? Will you need to synchronize in both directions, or will all your changes be made on one machine and then replicated to the other machine? If you only need one-way synchronization then usually you would clone the “original” repository instead of pushing its contents into a new one. If you need two-way synchronization, then it is best to have a bare repository to which they can both push and from which they can both fetch/pull.

Comment: @動靜能量: The key reason for the difficulties is that Git doesn't like to push into non-bare repositories - especially not the checked-out branch. If you do push to the checked-out branch, the work tree won't be touched; that's a scary operation if someone (even you!) might've been working in there.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you might have missed out on Git's notion of remotes. The top-level [`git remote`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html) command helps you perform some common operations. In particular, you'll want to create a remote:

```
git remote add foobar username@hostname/path/to/repo.git
```

And now you can use that remote's name instead of the URL:

```
git pull foobar master
git push foobar
```

If you've created a repository locally, then created the authoritative "central" one (common if you're the originator of a project), you might want to give your remote the default name `origin`, so that it'll feel like you cloned from that canonical repository. By default, `git push` (with no arguments) pushes all matching branches to origin, so this can be pretty handy.

You may also want to set up tracking branches, for example:

```
git branch --set-upstream master origin/master
```

That will tell Git that, when you have your master branch checked out and you run `git pull` (with no arguments), it should fetch and merge with origin's master branch.

Answer (score 0):

On the remote machine:

```
mkdir path/to/repo
cd path/to/repo
git init
git checkout -b tmp # Otherwise git will complain that master is already checked out.
```

On the local machine:

```
git add remote far_away username@remote_machine:path/to/repo
git push far_away master
```

Finally do `git checkout master` on the remote machine. There's no need for `git branch -d tmp`.

- `path/to/repo` is relative to `$HOME`. If you want an absolute path just prepend `/`, e.g. `username@remote_machine:/path/to/repo`.
- `far_away` is the name of the git "remote" - you can use anything though it probably makes sense to match the machine name, or something like `upstream` or `origin`.
- `username@` is optional.